# Inset data in EJB 3 (CRM Many to Many)

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, ejb-3.0, jsf-2.2

I have created a database. The database have 3 tables

- Users Table: username(PK), userpass
- Role Table: rolename(PK)
- User_Role Table: username(PK,FK), rolename(PK,FK) (References from User and Role tables)

Then I created a EJB3 project including Entities and Session bean for entityes for each table.

I used JSF2 and I have a Manage Bean to insert to those table

This is the page to pass data to the managed bean.

```
<h:form>
       <h:messages globalOnly="true"/>
       <h:inputText id="username" value="#{addBean.username}"/>
       <h:inputText id="password" value="#{addBean.userpass}"/>
       <h:inputText id="rolename" value="#{addBean.rolename}"/>
       <h:commandButton id="add" value="add" action="#{addBean.ADD()}"/>
    </h:form>
```

This is my Manage Bean:

```
package demo;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Sony
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AddBean {
    @EJB
    private UsersFacadeLocal usersFacade;
    @EJB
    private RolesFacadeLocal rolesFacade;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of AddBean
     */
    public AddBean() {
    }
    public void ADD()
    {
        Users u = new Users(username, userpass);
        Roles r = new Roles(rolename);
        usersFacade.create(u);
        rolesFacade.create(r);

        Users uC = usersFacade.find(username);
        Roles rC = rolesFacade.find(rolename);

        uC.getRolesCollection().add(rC);
        rC.getUsersCollection().add(uC);

     }

    private String username;
    private String userpass;
    private String rolename;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUserpass() {
        return userpass;
    }

    public void setUserpass(String userpass) {
        this.userpass = userpass;
    }

    public String getRolename() {
        return rolename;
    }

    public void setRolename(String rolename) {
        this.rolename = rolename;
    }
}
```

- Data pass to User and Role tables. But it doesn't pass data to User_Role table.
- I use GlassFish Server 4
  Any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try moving the two last lines in ADD() up to before you create() them

Comment: It throws an exception NullPointerException